# Are C++ strings mutable UNLIKE Java strings?

Tags: c++, string

Is it alright to manipulate strings in C++ this way:

```
string s = "Sting";
s[2] = 'a';
```

It works alright (and prints 'Sting'), but is it safe to do so?

If yes, does this mean they are mutable?

Comment: Yes, `std::string`s are mutable. String literals, however, are not.

Comment: That's most likely a C++ string. But you should clarify what exactly you mean.

Comment: Note: `char* s = "content"` is deprecated in C++, it should be the immutable `const char* s = "content"`. Assuming the string in your example is a std::string, yes the std::string and an array of chars s[] = "content"  (which is different to the char*/const char* above) are mutable.

Comment: @T.C : What do you mean by string literals, mate? I thought anything in double quotes is a string literal and as the example in the question shows, it was mutable.

Comment: @AnonymousAndy: This: `"String"` is a string literal. Its value is used to initialize `s`, which is an object of type `std::string`, *not* a string literal. The string literal is immutable; `s` is not.

Comment: But here is the difference between Java and C++ -- In C++, if you *attempt* to mutate a string-literal, the behavior is undefined.  Nothing stops you in C++ for attempting to mutate a string literal -- just be aware of the consequences.   In Java, you get an immediate indication that you've done something wrong.

Comment: No. The example above creates a string object on the stack and initializes the memory.it owns with "Sting". C++ is not at all like Java. Please get a good C++ book and read it. You'll be glad you did.

Comment: I removed "C" from the title. C does not have classes, not even a string class.

Answer (score 29):

C++ string literals, i.e., something like `"literal"` are immutable although C++03 allowed assigning a pointer to such a literal to a `char*` (this privilege was deprecated and removed for C++11). Trying to change a character of a string literal is undefined behavior:

```
char* s = "literal"; // OK with C++03; illegal with C++11 and later
s[0] = 'x';          // undefined behavior
```

C++ `std::string` objects are certainly mutable assuming they are not declared as `std::string const`. If you consider the sequence of `char` objects to be independent of each other it is OK to assign to individual objects. It is, however, quite common that the strings actually contain Unicode encoded as UTF-8 bytes. If that's the case changing any element of the string may destroy the proper encoding, e.g., because a continuation byte gets replaced by something else.

So, yes, the strings are mutable but it may not be safe from a semantic point of view to assign to individual elements.

Answer (score 19):

**The string literal itself is immutable just like in Java.**

String literals are stored in a read-only part of memory.

For example, if you do something like the following, you will get a segfault:

```
char *ptr = (char *) "hello";
ptr[0] = 'a';  //segfault! you can't change something that's immutable
```

However! You can modify the string using `s[2] = 'a'`, unless the string is declared with the const keyword,

The reason for this is that the `=` operator for strings is overloaded, takes the string literal as an argument, and then loops through the string literal copying each character into a mutable char array.

So if you're comparing string literals in Java and C/C++, they have the same behavior when it comes to being immutable. Instances of the C++ string class are mutable, but instances of the Java String class are immutable.

Here's an example displaying the fact that the string has a copy:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
  const char *ptr = "hello";
  string s = ptr;

  s[0] = 'b';

  cout << s << endl; //prints bello
  cout << ptr << endl; //prints hello

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please please explain what you mean by string literals not being immutable. I mean, anything in double quotes in a string literal, right? And in the example I provided, we did mutate it. Please explain brother.

Comment: Yes, anything in double quotes is a string literal.  This string is stored in a read-only part of memory.  Therefore it's immutable since you can't write to this memory.  In the example you provided, you did NOT mutate the string literal.  You mutated a copy of it that was stored in the String object.  I'lll type up an example that makes this concept super clear.

Comment: @AnonymousAndy - That first line in your example takes the string literal, and creates a std::string `object` from the literal.  It is no different in concept than you doing `int a = 1;`  You can change the value of `a`, correct?  But you can't change `1`.

Answer (score 4):

C++ `std::string` is mutable and assignment (generally) copies the string data. Java `String` is immutable and assignment copies a reference to the string.

The type `std::shared_ptr< const std::string >` is to some degree like a Java string. However, it's a poor man's substitute. In C++03 it was relevant for optimizing e.g. sorting of collections of strings, but with C++11 move semantics it's no longer so relevant for anything – except the academic POV.

Answer (score 3):

Yes and Yes.

It is like modifying an array at position 2.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is perfectly safe and yes strings are mutable, meaning you can change them, append new stuff to them and also remove parts from them.

Answer (score 1):

Strings in C++ are mutable, but with great power comes great responsibility: you will get undefined behavior if you read from or store to string memory that is out of bounds. E.g., in your example, if you referred to s[12], you would get undefined behavior.

Answer (score -1):

String
C++ mutable.  (String data copied)
Python Immutable (String reference copied)
Java Immutable (String reference copied)