# I wonder why std::string::c_str() returns const char * type

Tags: c++, string, char, constants

I wonder why std::string::c_str() returns const char * type even though sting is char array type.

```
    string s("Hello");
```

There is a string s.
It consists of a char-type array and

```
s[1] = 'a';
```

I can also change the elements as above.
However, if I call c_str() to know the starting address of the string within the string object, It returns const char * type.

Therefore, I must use strcpy() to convert it to a char-type array.

Why does It return the const type?

Comment: This is how encapsulation works in general. It manages its own memory, and you are not allowed to modify it directly. Only through the public member functions it gives you.

Comment: Thank you for your kind answer. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2):

Having certain primitives be immutable helps drive efficiency.  If the compiler knows that you're not allowed to change a value, it can optimize in ways that are not possible for mutable values.

Similarly, constant values can be guarded against buffer overflow attempts using new CPU memory guard features that didn't exist when K&R first built C.

Those are some of the arguments for having an immutable String primitive.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28442823/1168588

Comment: Thank you! Thanks to you, my curiosity has been solved.