# can we modify object members without soliciting the object

Tags: c++

I want to be sure of that, If I have a pointer that points to a member by reference and I'm trying to change its value outside of the class and without going through its object -> (violation).

thank you for confirming to me what I said because I am reading book of
[Effective C++: 55 Specific Ways to Improve Your Programs and Designs](https://www.amazon.fr/Effective-Specific-Improve-Programs-Designs/dp/0321334876) (page 22) and I come across his example that stung me

```
     class text{
        public:
        text(int c):
        _c(c)
        {}
        int& operator[](int position){
            return _c;
        }
        private:
        int _c;
    };


    int main(){

    text t = text(5);
    std::cout<< t[0] << std::endl;
    int* p = &t[0];
    *p = 10;
    std::cout<< t[0] << std::endl;
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Fundamentally your problem is storing a string literal as a `char*` instead of `const char*` as you are not permitted to reassign to the elements of a string literal. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28442719/are-c-strings-mutable-unlike-java-strings/28442823

Comment: If `text t = text("hello");` compiles, you are using a very old compiler. You can't point to a string literal with a non-`const` pointer. This used to be allowed for compatibility with C code, but this has been removed from the language. The problem with your code is you are ultimately trying to change a string literal which is Undefined Behavior.

Comment: page22 has stuff about const member functions

Comment: i just updated the code with integers instead.
because my basic question is not related to char * / const char * but rather on the fact that a pointer to a member function by reference can modify the member of the class and it is the case

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your updated code - access protection applies to names, not data. (And your modification is equivalent to `t[0] = 10;`.)

Comment: That is not what's in the book. What's the question?

Comment: *this code throws an exception* No it does not. *violation* Says who? Quotation please. There is no violation.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I just update the topic

Comment: You have to go through the object at some point, but not necessarily at or near the point where you modify its data. You go through the object when you call its `operator[]`. Once `operator[]` returns a reference to a member, you are free to modify that member through that reference at any later time. It's completely valid.

Comment: What do you mean by "soliciting the object"?  See https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/solicit

Answer (score 0):

In C++, we must use a *pointer to `const`* char, that is `const char*` to point to a **string literal**. So the code shown below is incorrect:

```
char *ptr = "a string literal; //incorrect
```

Correct way to write this would be:

```
const char*ptr = "a string literal"; //correct
```

Your code has the same problem. You have a data member `char*` named `_c` that points to a string literal. You can see [here](https://onlinegdb.com/6Li-gLQCC)  that the program doesn't compile.

**Answer to your Edit**

As shown in your modified code snippet, we are allowed to return a reference to a data member and then use that to modify the data member without using any member function or the object itself to which the data member belongs! But note this is *not advised* and is not the goal of OOP.

It is **not advisable** because you're providing a **backdoor** to your data members. Now the user can do whatever he/she wants with that data member's value. For example he/she can change its value directly as you did or he/she can do some operation on it that should not be allowed. Lets take another example, say we have a `class` called `Book` and lets say it has 3 data members `price`, `numberOfPages`, and `dateOfBuy`. Now say the `price` of the book is calculated as

```
price = numberOfPages * dateOfBuy;
```

Now if you return a reference to `price` data member then **there is a problem**. The user can set the price according to his/her will.
He/she can even set the `price = 0;` while the price had to be calculated by multiplying the other two data member's value. But the user bypassed this protection. This is what i meant by **opening a backdoor**. The example would look something like:

```
#include <iostream>
 class Book{
        public:
        Book(int pnumberOfPages, int pdateOfBuy): numberOfPages(pnumberOfPages), dateOfBuy(pdateOfBuy)
        {
            price = numberOfPages * dateOfBuy;
        }
        
        
        int& operator[](int position){
            return price;
        }
        private:
        int price = 0, numberOfPages = 0, dateOfBuy = 0;
    };


    int main(){

    Book t = Book(5, 5);//now price should be 5 * 5 = 25
    std::cout<< t[0] << std::endl;//this will print 25
    
    int* p = &t[0]; 
    
    //Be aware !! You are changing the data member price's value without going through an object
    *p = 10;//in practice, we should not be able to change the price at will but since we have a pointer we can
    std::cout<< t[0] << std::endl; //this will print 10
    return 0;
    }
```

**Secondly** by "not the goal of OOP" i mean that now you can access the private data members directly without using the interface of the class.

> If I have a pointer that points to a member by reference and I'm trying to change its value outside of the class and without going through its object -> (violation)

So as you can see that you are changing the data member `price`'s value without going through object, which is what your question(as quoted above) asked/said.

This is the **primary reason** we use `setters` and `getters` like `setMember` and `getMember`(that don't return by reference). For example instead of returning a reference to the price member we should return it by value using `getPrice()` as shown below:

```
//return by value and not by reference
int getPrice() const
{
return price;
}
```

Now we are returning the `price` data member by value instead of by reference. And so the user cannot access the `price` directly.

Similarly for setting the value of a data member lets say `numberOfDays` we can add a `setNumber` as :

```
void setNumber(int pNumberofdays)
{
  numberOfDays = pNumberofdays;//this sets the data member numberOfDays' value. 
}
```

**setters** are used to set a data member's value while **getters** are used to get(**by value** and not by reference) the data member's value.

Comment: @KennyOstrom I have added the answer to OP's modified question in my edit. Check it out.

Comment: @AnoopRana why is it not advisable? I think that's why we usually start with get/set functions instead of using get by reference which can get and set members.

Comment: @anes47 I have explained it in my answer. Check it out.

Comment: thank you for your explanation. but in ur example `price` shouldn't have access via operator[] it's clear. I am rather aiming there where we use `set` functions to set member data I do not see the difference between using `setMemeber()` and declaring a `getMemeber()` by reference so you can do the get and set via the same function

Comment: @anes47 I have added "**why we need** `setMember` and `getMember`" in my answer. Check it out. Also note that `setMember` and `getMember` *should never return* a data member by reference otherwise you will have the same problem that i already explained in my answer.

Comment: If I want to set and get the same member in this case I can use `getMember()` with reference and not two fucntions `setMember()` and `getMember()`, u agree ?

Comment: @anes47 Do you mean that first you use `getMember` that returns by reference. Next you use that returned value to directly "set" the member's value without using `setMember` ? If the answer to my above question is yes, then yes you can do it but you will face the same problems that i explained in my answer. If the answer to my question is no, then *can you explain* (clarify) likely **using code** what do you mean by " If I want to set and get the same member in this case I can use get with reference".